# Problems installing packages via elpa that require cl-lib-1.0

Tags: package, package-repositories

I'm having problems installing package from `(m)elpa` which require `cl-lib-1.0`.

My `emacs` version is `24.3`, hence I have a builtin copy of `cl-lib-1.0`, however, the only version available via `elpa` is 0.5. Unfortunately the dependency resolution does not seem to understand that my builtin `cl-lib` is more recent (and adequate), hence it installs `cl-lib` in v0.5.

The packages in question are `shift-text` and `stripe-buffer` available on `melpa`.

I'm using a function for batch install of all packages, you can find the relevant code [here](http://pastebin.com/aniDPFxU).

A working (workaround) solution is to uninstall `cl-lib-0.5` via `list-packages` and then manually install the package(s) in question. [Therefore I think the actual culprit is my batch install routine?] However, I'd like to continue using my batch installation procedure, hence the question

> How do you tell `package.el` that a certain package is already installed in a given version?

**Edit:** Btw, this problem has surfaced previously, however, the discussion in [this](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/paradox/issues/14) `github` issue does not properly solve it.

Comment: As a test could you try adding an explicit call to `(require 'cl-lib)`?

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin I added the `require` statement just above the package installation code, however, this did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version of `cl-lib` in GNU Elpa is a backport of the `cl-lib` from Emacs 24.3 intended for Emacs <=24.2. (Or put differently it is a forward compatibility wrapper around `cl` as it comes with <=24.2). If you are using Emacs 24.3 then you don't need it and when you use `package.el` from that Emacs version it will never install any version of `cl-lib` because it is aware that that is a built-in library/package.

So just uninstall `cl-lib`, you probably installed it when still using an older Emacs version. If `package.el` actually tries to install `cl-lib` while using Emacs 24.3, then you have to investigate why that happens, it shouldn't.

The second issue is that the mentioned packages depend on version `1.0` of `cl-lib` when they should instead depend on `0.5` so that they can be used with older Emacsen. If they cannot be used with older Emacsen that should be made explicit by depending on `(emacs "24.3")`. Please open issues against these packages so that this can be fixed.

Comment: `cl-lib` is reinstalled in v0.5 at every startup, that is the whole point... I suspect that my batch install code is at fault, however, I have not clue why / how.

Comment: Is `cl-lib` explicitly listed in the part you elided (`;; [...] other packages`)?

Comment: It was not. **But** you put me on the right track. I was modifying that list at another point and that added a stray `cl-lib`. Reverting the list to its original value stopped the installation of `cl-lib`. It appears that while debugging the human error became the true bug ;-).

Comment: Hehe. Also `package.el`s dependency handling is *very* rudimentary. All it understands is *at least version V of package X*, something more elaborate like *exactly version V* ain't possible. That is a limitation in `package.el` but I don't think that it would do much good to support this at this point anyway, not until Emacs has modules; what if Y depends on `=X-1` while Z depends on `>=X-2`? So this forces authors of Y and Z to always support the latest version of X which isn't necessarily a bad thing. But it would be useful if `package.el` refused to install multiple versions of the same p.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs' `package.el` *always* downloads the highest versioned package it can find, and I don't know a way to stop it from doing so, in general. You can, however, specify which repository your package comes from, using the `package-pinned-packages` variable, available through the customization menu for Emacs >= 24.4. I use it to "pin" packages I use to MELPA Stable rather than MELPA, for example. If you don't, and you update, say, `zenburn-theme`, you will always get `zenburn-theme` version 20151003.2346 (or whatever version is most current) in MELPA rather than version 2.2 (today's most current) from MELPA Stable. (I have both archives in my `package-archives` list.) This way I at least can make Emacs stick to something a package author has marked as a stable version, not the latest commit he or she has made to Github.

This helps with versioning to a small degree, but doesn't really answer your question, since you are trying to keep `package.el` from downloading anything that will shadow your built-in package. Unfortunately, `package-pinned-packages` will only let you specify a repository listed in `package-archives`. Emacs' "built-in" package archive isn't listed there, at least on my Emacs 24.5, so that isn't an option for your situation. (Emacs maintainers: how about putting a "built-in" archive in there by default?)

You say you have a function for batch install of all packages, so presumably you don't mind writing a little lisp code. Emacs 24.5 (and maybe earlier) `package.el` has a function `package-built-in-p` which will let you test whether a package is built in or not. From the documentation,

```
Return true if PACKAGE is built-in to Emacs. Optional arg MIN-VERSION, 
if non-nil, should be a version list specifying the minimum acceptable
version.
```

This lets you specify a minimum acceptable version, but not a maximum acceptable version, or even (I wish) a particular version. You can use it to determine whether a package in your batch list is built-in or not, and exclude it from your list if it is. Or you could just exclude it from your list and uninstall the version you already have in your `elpa` directory, as a previous poster suggested.

You could set up your own `local` package archive, put your preferred version in there, and pin your package to `local`. This way you get total control over the versioning. See [How can I set up an Elpa server?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17401/how-can-i-set-up-an-elpa-server/17408#17408) for directions. Now that I think about it, this may be a good idea for many reasons...