# How can I set up an ELPA server?

Tags: package-repositories

A buddy and I are wanting to start writing emacs packages specific for use in our company.  (Trust me, nothing we write will be of much interest to anyone outside -- it's integration with internal tools.)

We'd like to make package installation and maintenance as easy as possible and we think this means integration with `package.el`.  What do we need to do to set up a repository for such use?

Comment: I'd fork MELPA and write recipes for your packages!  Alternatively,  provide just the recipes and point your coworkers to QUELPA.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I set up a local package archive (Emacs 24.5) using `package.el` by first creating two directories, `pkgs` and `local`. (The names don't matter.) The files comprising your packages go in `pkgs`, and `local` will end up holding your archive. If you want to make an archive available to others, you can expose `local` using a web server, but the process is the same as building a local archive.

I put the following in my `init.el` file:

```el
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)

(require 'package-x)
(defvar local-archive
  (expand-file-name "local/" user-emacs-directory)
  "Location of the package archive.")
(setq package-archive-upload-base local-archive)
(add-to-list 'package-archives `("local" . ,local-archive) t)

(package-initialize)
```

I put my archive in my `.emacs.d` directory (hence the `user-emacs-directory` in the `expand-file-name` form) but you can put it anywhere you like.

Once this is evaluated, execute `M-x package-upload-file` and enter the file name of your package to be installed. This will generate a new package in `local`. You will see three new files in there, `archive-contents`, `yourpackagename-version.el`, and `yourpackagename-readme.txt`. Now you should be able to do `M-x package-list-packages` and see your package listed. With luck, they'll be at the top marked "new". You can install the package as usual, and you will see it show up in your `.emacs.d/elpa` directory just like any other package.

This should work out of the box for Emacs 24. I'm not sure about earlier versions. Your users can access your package in the usual way by including

```el
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
  '("archive" . "http://yourdomain.com/path-to-local-dir/"))
(package-initialize)
```

in their `init.el` file.

For information on how to write a package, see [Preparing Lisp code for distribution](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Packaging.html#Packaging) in the GNU Emacs Lisp manual.

Comment: Thanks! This is a very well-written answer and it worked well for me. I have just one question.. when I do `M-x package-update-file`, it puts the `.el` file directly under `local/` dir. Is there a way to create a subdirectory for each package so that we end up with `local/pkg1/pkg1.el`, `local/pkg2/pkg2.el`, ... ?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. The `elpa` directory is set up the way you describe. I really don't know why `local` is not. Bear in mind that these files are generated automatically, so no one ever really has to look at them. I keep my files under version control with git, and put my `local` directory into `.gitignore` for that reason. I keep my `pkgs` directory nicely organized, and under version control, but `local` is what it is.

Comment: Thanks. So to confirm, all files gets dumped in a flat hierarchy in your `local/` too? I wanted the hierarchical arrangement so that I can specify the package's URL meta data as `;; URL: http://yourdomain.com/path-to-local-dir/pkg1`, and so on for different packages. But it's not a big deal. I am more thrilled to publish my packages in a local elpa. :)

Comment: Mine is flat, too. I wouldn't point your users to that `local` directory anyway. Point them to the original source instead.

Comment: This is great! But when I use it with tar files on windows, a broken tar is uploaded and I have to manually copy over it again. Bug in Emacs? 24.5

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to host something like MELPA, you can find instructions on MELPA's wiki on how to host your own MELPA instance:

https://github.com/melpa/melpa/wiki/Custom-Melpa-Archive

Essentially, it boils down to:

1. Fork/clone [the MELPA GitHub repository](https://github.com/melpa/melpa)
2. Delete all existing recipes from the `recipes/` directory
3. Add your own recipes
4. Run `make`.